# Скрипт не меняет значение в базе данных

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, ubuntu

На сервере поднята база данных MariaDB. При авторизации пользователя значение online должно меняться с 0 на 1.Если вводить в консоли команду, она меняет значение, но именно в скрипте нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$bd = mysqli_connect("localhost","****","******");
mysqli_select_db($bd,"*****");
$user = getenv("username");
$password = getenv("password");
$nowtime=time();
$qr="SELECT * FROM users where username='".$user."' AND password='".$password."' AND date>".$nowtime;
$query=mysqli_query($bd,$qr) or die(mysqli_error());
$strok=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$status = "SELECT * FROM users where online and username = '".$user."'; 
if (if $status == 0)
"UPDATE users SET online = 1 where username = '".$user."';
if ($strok==1)
exit(0);
else
exit(1);
?>
```

весь код работает, за исключением UPDATE.

Comment: У вас есть строка, содержащая текст update, но она даже не в переменной и функциям mysqli для выполнения не передается. С таким же успехом можно написать этот update просто на бумажке и ждать пока он выполнится

Comment: $q = "UPDATE users SET online = 1 where username = '".$user."';
достаточно? Если да. то все равно не помогает, если нет то подскажите реализацию, пожалуйста.

Comment: $q это просто переменная. от того что строка где то в памяти она не выполняется. Что бы запрос выполнился его надо отправить в базу данных, например с помощью mysqli_query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$bd = mysqli_connect("localhost","****","******");
mysqli_select_db($bd,"*****");
$user = getenv("username");
$password = getenv("password");
$nowtime=time();
$qr="SELECT * FROM users where username='$user' AND password='$password' AND date>'$nowtime'";
$query=mysqli_query($bd,$qr) or die(mysqli_error());
$strok=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$qr = "SELECT * FROM users where username = '$user'"; 
$query=mysqli_query($bd,$qr) or die(mysqli_error());
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($query);
if ($row['online'] == 0){
    $qr="UPDATE users SET online = 1 where username = '$user'";
    $query=mysqli_query($bd,$qr) or die(mysqli_error());
}
if ($strok==1)
exit(0);
else
exit(1);
?>
```